# Android Facebook Integration : How to perform Invite Friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-invite

I am new to Android Facebook Integration, How to **`Invite Friends`** on facebook using `Android Facebook SDK` ?

Is there any demo or Example?

You help would be Appreciated, Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebDialogs class, specifically the [WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder) to build an invite dialog.

You can also have a look at the RPS sample that ships with the SDK, and in the "See Friends" section, there's an example request dialog.